# Paginating chronologically prioritized Firebase children

Tags: firebase

**tl;dr** Performing basic pagination in Firebase via `startAt`, `endAt` and `limit` is terribly complicated, there must be an easier way.

I'm constructing an administration interface for a large number of user submissions. My initial (and current) idea is to simply fetch everything and perform pagination on the client.  There is however a noticable delay when fetching 2000+ records (containing 5-6 small number/string fields each) which I attribute to a data payload of over 1.5mb.

Currently all entries are added via [`push`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html) but I'm a bit lost as to how paginate through the huge list.

To fetch the first page of data I'm using [`endAt`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/endat.html) with a [`limit`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/limit.html) of 5:

```
ref.endAt().limit(10).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.name(), snapshot.val().name)
})
```

which results in the following:

```
-IlNo79stfiYZ61fFkx3 #46 John
-IlNo7AmMk0iXp98oKh5 #47 Robert
-IlNo7BeDXbEe7rB6IQ3 #48 Andrew
-IlNo7CX-WzM0caCS0Xp #49 Frank
-IlNo7DNA0SzEe8Sua16 #50 Jimmmy
```

Firstly to figure out how many pages there are I am keeping a separate counter that's updated whenever someone adds or removes a record.

Secondly since I'm using `push` I have no way of navigating to a specific page since I don't know the name of the last record for a specific page meaning an interface like this is not currently possible:

[image: Standard pagination controls]

To make it simpler I decided on simply having next/previous buttons, this however also presents a new problem; if I use the name of the first record in the previous result-set I can paginate to the next page using the following:

```
ref.endAt(null, '-IlNo79stfiYZ61fFkx3').limit(5).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.name(), snapshot.val().name)
})
```

The result of this operation is as follows:

```
-IlNo76KDsN53rB1xb-K #42 William
-IlNo77CtgQvjuonF2nH #43 Christian
-IlNo7857XWfMipCa8bv #44 Jim
-IlNo78z11Bkj-XJjbg_ #45 Richard
-IlNo79stfiYZ61fFkx3 #46 John
```

Now I have the next page except it's shifted one position meaning I have to adjust my limit and ignore the last record.

To move back one page I'll have to keep a separate list on the client of every record I've received so far and figure out what name to pass to `startAt`.

Is there an easier way of doing this or should I just go back to fetching everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're working on adding an "offset()" query to allow for easy pagination. We'll also be adding a special endpoint to allow you to read the number of children at a location without actually loading them from the server.

Both of these are going to take a bit though. In the meantime the method you describe (or doing it all on the client) are probably your best bet.

If you have a data structure that is append-only, you could potentially also do pagination when you write the data. For example: put the first 50 in /page1, put the second 50 in /page2, etc.

Comment: Thanks, offset() and count() will solve all pagination problems.

Comment: Any update on when these features will be released for the JavaScript API - Specifically with support for AngularFire bindings?

Comment: +1 for the question from @DanKanze. This would be great, especially for AngularFire.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to accomplish this is with two trees:

Tree of ids: {
id1: id1,
id2: id2,
id3: id3
}

Tree of data: {
id1: ...,
id2: ...,
id3: ...
}

You can then load the entire tree of ids (or a big chunk of it) to the client, and do fancy pagination with that tree of ids.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack for paginate in each direction.

```
// get 1-5
ref.startAt().limit(5)

// get 6-10 from 5
ref.startAt(null, '5th-firebase-id' + 1).limit(5)

// get 11-15 from 10
ref.startAt(null, '10th-firebase-id' + 1).limit(5)
```

Basically it's a hack for `startAtExclusive()`. You can anything to the end of the id.

Also figured out `endAtExclusive()` for going backwards.

```
// get 6-10 from 11
ref.endAt(null, '11th-firebase-id'.slice(0, -1)).limit(5)... 

// get 1-5 from 6
ref.endAt(null, '6th-firebase-id'.slice(0, -1)).limit(5)...
```

Will play with this some more but seems to work with push ids. Replace limit with `limitToFirst` or `limitToLast` if using firebase queries.